# Tufte-handout class and Indentation

Tags: indentation, tufte

I'm using `tufte-handout` class. I'd like to avoid indentation discrepancies in the side-notes. In particular I would like the beginning of each line in a side note to be (by default) equally indented. But, so far what I have is only this:

```
    \documentclass{tufte-handout}

    \geometry{lmargin=72pt,tmargin=72pt,textwidth=350pt,marginparwidth=144pt}    
    \usepackage[english]{babel}        
    \usepackage{graphicx} % allow embedded images
       \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth,totalheight=\textheight,keepaspectratio}
       \graphicspath{{graphics/}} % set of paths to search for images
    \usepackage{amsmath}  % extended mathematics
    \usepackage{booktabs} % book-quality tables
    \usepackage{units}    % non-stacked fractions and better unit spacing
    \usepackage{multicol} % multiple column layout facilities
    \usepackage{lipsum}   % filler text
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{upgreek}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{marvosym}

    \newcommand\blfootnote[1]{\begingroup
         \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
         \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
         \endgroup
          }

    \usepackage{fancyvrb} % extended verbatim environments
        \fvset{fontsize=\normalsize}% default font size for fancy-verbatim environments

    \newcommand{\doccmd}[1]{\texttt{\textbackslash#1}}
    \newcommand{\docopt}[1]   {\ensuremath{\langle}\textrm{\textit{#1}}\ensuremath{\rangle}}% optional command argument
    \newcommand{\docarg}[1]{\textrm{\textit{#1}}}% (required) command argument
    \newcommand{\docenv}[1]{\textsf{#1}}% environment name
    \newcommand{\docpkg}[1]{\texttt{#1}}% package name
    \newcommand{\doccls}[1]{\texttt{#1}}% document class name
    \newcommand{\docclsopt}[1]{\texttt{#1}}% document class option name
    \newenvironment{docspec}{\begin{quote}\noindent}{\end{quote}}% command specification environment

    \newcounter{savedenumi}
    \newenvironment{moreenum}{%
      \setcounter{savedenumi}{\value{enumi}}%
       \begin{enumerate}\setcounter{enumi}{\value{savedenumi}}%
        }{%
       \end{enumerate}%
     }

    \title{Title}

    \author[Author]{Author}


    \begin{document}
    \section{Section}\label{sec:Section}
       \begin{itemize} 
         \item Item1\blfootnote{This is a side note,\\and this is a side note;\\this is a side note, too.}
         \item Item2
         \item Item3
         \end{itemize}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Can you better describe the effect you're wanting to achieve? Do you want to remove the indentation in front of all paragraphs in a sidenote? Do you want the number to hang in front of the sidenote and the sidenote text to start flush left? How should multiple paragraphs appear in a single sidenote? Do you want to remove the number in front of sidenotes? (Are you looking for the `\marginnote` command?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You redefining `\thefootnote` to be empty → `\renewcommand\thefootnote{}`. Hence the space (usually) occupied by the footnote number becomes free and the sentence starts early.

You may push the first  sentence in the footnote by an amount equal to the space occupied by the footnote number by `\phantom{\thefootnote}`.

```
\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{\begingroup
         \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{\phantom{\thefootnote} #1}%
         \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
         \endgroup
          }
```

Full code:

```
  \documentclass{tufte-handout}

    \geometry{lmargin=72pt,tmargin=72pt,textwidth=350pt,marginparwidth=144pt}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{graphicx} % allow embedded images
       \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth,totalheight=\textheight,keepaspectratio}
       \graphicspath{{graphics/}} % set of paths to search for images
    \usepackage{amsmath}  % extended mathematics
    \usepackage{booktabs} % book-quality tables
    \usepackage{units}    % non-stacked fractions and better unit spacing
    \usepackage{multicol} % multiple column layout facilities
    \usepackage{lipsum}   % filler text
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{upgreek}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{marvosym}

    \newcommand\blfootnote[1]{\begingroup
         \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{\phantom{\thefootnote} #1}%
         \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
         \endgroup
          }

    \usepackage{fancyvrb} % extended verbatim environments
        \fvset{fontsize=\normalsize}% default font size for fancy-verbatim environments

    \newcommand{\doccmd}[1]{\texttt{\textbackslash#1}}
    \newcommand{\docopt}[1]   {\ensuremath{\langle}\textrm{\textit{#1}}\ensuremath{\rangle}}% optional command argument
    \newcommand{\docarg}[1]{\textrm{\textit{#1}}}% (required) command argument
    \newcommand{\docenv}[1]{\textsf{#1}}% environment name
    \newcommand{\docpkg}[1]{\texttt{#1}}% package name
    \newcommand{\doccls}[1]{\texttt{#1}}% document class name
    \newcommand{\docclsopt}[1]{\texttt{#1}}% document class option name
    \newenvironment{docspec}{\begin{quote}\noindent}{\end{quote}}% command specification environment

    \newcounter{savedenumi}
    \newenvironment{moreenum}{%
      \setcounter{savedenumi}{\value{enumi}}%
       \begin{enumerate}\setcounter{enumi}{\value{savedenumi}}%
        }{%
       \end{enumerate}%
     }

    \title{Title}

    \author[Author]{Author}


    \begin{document}
    \section{Section}\label{sec:Section}
       \begin{itemize}
         \item Item1\blfootnote{This is a side note,\\and this is a side note;\\this is a side note, too.}
         \item Item2
         \item Item3
         \end{itemize}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Congrats on passing the 70K points mark!!

Comment: @Mico So nice of you. Thank you for the kind words. :)